# Setting up PhoneGap and Dreamweaver CS 5.5 (iOS Developer Tools)

Tags: ios, cordova, sdk, path, dreamweaver

I'm trying to configure the application framework for Dreamweaver CS 5.5 in conjunction with phonegap. On my Mac HD, I have a folder called "Developer" with XCode in it.

In Dreamweaver, under Sites>Mobile Applications>Configure Application Framework, I get the window asking for the Android SDK Path and the iOS Developer Tools Path. In the second field, I enter "/Developer"

When I hit "Save" I get an error message saying "Neither Android or iOS SDKs are installed. You need to setup at least one SDK in order to build applications."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The newest version. I've tried it in both places, with XCode in both places. Same result

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer thanks to Tribe on Mars

http://tribeonmars.blogspot.com/2012/03/dreamweaver-and-xcode-and-developer.html

> Since Xcode 4.3 removed Developer folder and put it under /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer.